# Should Apache Flink be used for historical querying

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, event-sourcing

I'm designing an event-sourced architecture based around Kafka, and using Flink for stream processing.

One use case will be the querying (filtering and sorting of results) of historical trade data that has passed through the Kafka topic over time.  e.g. "Give me all trades in the last 5 years with these attributes, sorted by xx".  Total trade history will be around 10m, increasing by say 1m/year.

Is Flink itself the right tool for such historical queries, and able to do so with reasonable performance (a few seconds)?  Or am I better feeding the events from Kafka into an indexable/queryable data store like MongoDB/RDBMS, and using that for historical queries?

Doing the former feels like it'll adhere more closely to a Kappa Architecture, whereas resorting to a historical db feels like I'm moving away from that back towards a Lambda architecture.

Comment: If I would be you I would make a MVP with the two and see the difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Flink is well suited to process historic data from a Kafka topic (or any other data source) due to its support for event-time processing, i.e., time-based processing based on timestamps in the records not based on the clock of the processing machine (aka processing-time).

If you only want to perform analytics, you might want to have a look at Flink's SQL support.